# WSO2 ESB - Could not initialize Start up controller. TaskManager not found. {org.apache.synapse.startup.quartz.StartUpController

Tags: wso2

I have written a scheduled task which makes use of default implementation, that comes with wso2 esb 4.9.
Problem is as soon as I trigger the job, I am getting this error
 Could not initialize Start up controller. TaskManager not found. `{org.apache.synapse.startup.quartz.StartUpController}.`
The same is working fine with wso2 4.8.

Comment: Can you please share the config of your task scheduler? Please see (http://wokis.blogspot.com/2016/05/task-scheduling-through-wso2-esb-490.html) and check the configuration is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please add the following xml entry under the `<definitions>` tag. Go to ESB admin console, under main menu go to source view and copy the following xml entry inside the `<definitions>` tag.

```
<taskManager provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager"/>
```

This should solve your issue.