# WSO2 ESB - Cluster Environment Task Scheduling

Tags: scheduled-tasks, wso2-esb

I have a cluster environment which has a master and worker node (Hybrid configuration where master node also acts as a worker node). When I try to schedule a task on the master node, It gave an error

```
WSO2 ESB - Could not initialize Start up controller. TaskManager not found. 
{org.apache.synapse.startup.quartz.StartUpController
```

which this post gave a solution

[WSO2 ESB - Could not initialize Start up controller. TaskManager not found. {org.apache.synapse.startup.quartz.StartUpController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109489/wso2-esb-could-not-initialize-start-up-controller-taskmanager-not-found-org)

I added the required attribute and now I'am getting the following error.

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager} -  Scheduling task [[NTask::-1234::TestShedTsk]::synapse.simple.quartz] FAILED. Error: No available task nodes for resolving a task location {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager}
org.wso2.carbon.ntask.common.TaskException: No available task nodes for resolving a task location
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.clustered.ClusteredTaskManager.getTaskLocation(ClusteredTaskManager.java:232)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.clustered.ClusteredTaskManager.locateMemberForTask(ClusteredTaskManager.java:209)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.clustered.ClusteredTaskManager.getMemberIdFromTaskName(ClusteredTaskManager.java:283)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.clustered.ClusteredTaskManager.scheduleTask(ClusteredTaskManager.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager.schedule(NTaskTaskManager.java:103)
    at org.apache.synapse.task.TaskScheduler.scheduleTask(TaskScheduler.java:140)
    at org.apache.synapse.startup.quartz.StartUpController.submitTask(StartUpController.java:150)
```

I have done the changes in the `task-config.xml` located in `<ESB_HOME>\repository\conf\etc` directory.

```
<taskServerMode>CLUSTERED</taskServerMode>

<taskServerCount>2</taskServerCount>
```

even though I'm still getting the above error.

Comment: Does this help: [http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2015-July/051321.html](http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2015-July/051321.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and but I have tried those, and my environment is one worker one master. I don't start with `DworkerNode=true` but I have done the configuration in the `carbon.xml` configuration file. Other artifacts are being synced, except task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that error, you should have to start worker nodes with worker profile. As follows;

```
sh wso2server.sh -DworkerNode=true
```

When you are going to start Manager without workers, it may pop that error as worker nodes are not yet started. After you started worker nodes with worker profile, error should not be shown again.

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks for the time